# website doesn't load

Tags: users

I had a fully working Drupal site and had some problems with uploading files on a specific page.  So I started looking closely at the code and noticed some oddities (basically a lot of random characters).  I removed the code and everything seemed to be fine.  The code had to do with the images on the page.  Then all of a sudden I started receiving a "page cannot be displayed" error, and was not able to view the site anymore.

I had someone else look at the server and they were able to connect just fine.  To be on the safe side, they rebuilt the page.  I tried again, and still couldn't see the website.

I then tried to attempt the connection through another network I manage via VPN.  Coming at it from the other network, the page loads.  I've tried Firefox, Chrome, Safari, all with the same result.  I tried clearing the cache, reset settings, delete and reinstall.  I've restarted my router.  I'm out of ideas.  This has been super frustrating.  Thanks for any help.

Update:  I talked to the person hosting this and they mentioned they run something called Liquid Web.  I guess it bans your IP if it thinks you're doing something bad.  All I did was modify a page it banned me.

Comment: so you can connect to your server, ok, but...in your server is apache and mysql running?

Comment: I can't connect to the server unless I VPN to another network.  It's almost like I'm being blocked by a local firewall after I made the code change.  I haven't changed this firewall for months. Is it even possible to block durpal specifically at the firewall level?  Every other website loads.

Comment: `I can't connect to the server unless I VPN to another network.` sounds like its your computer's firewall, or antivirus and It's only blocking your website url.

Comment: I agree but just wanted to double check if there was something drupal that could cause this problem.  This all worked till I changed the drupal code on the server.  I've already uninstalled the AV that was installed, removed and reinstalled firefox, and rebooted the firewall.  I've cleared browser cache, flushed dns.....whats left to try?

Comment: humm.. unless your website ip ban you? I wouldn't know how to fix that.

Comment: I found this https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/ban

Answer (score 3):

You don't go into any detail about what the page won't load means.  Is there an error that is being displayed by the browser?  If so what is it?  In this case it is likely that you are getting some kind of http error code back from the server, or the request is timing out.

You may want to look at your server's fail2ban log.  If Fail2ban is enabled, it is possible that your ip address has been blocked.

Is there an error in a web page?  Do you get a blank page?  If so, does viewing page source show anything?

Errors in the web page are much more likely an sign of something coming from drupal.  Though http error codes could easily be coming from drupal too.

If you use the developer tools in whatever browser you are using to look at the request and response headers what do you see?

This will give you a clearer view of what is being requested and what the server is answering?

Do you see anything in your server's error log?  Does anything show up in the access log?  This will give you a clearer view of whether the request is reaching your web server at all.  If you see no request in either the access or error logs, it is a reasonably good bet that you are being blocked at the firewall level (this includes fail2ban) or that you have some local dns setting that is causing your request to go to the wrong place.  (This could be something in your /etc/hosts)

Comment: The message is "page cannot be displayed".  I mentioned that in my OP.  I should have mentioned that I don't manage the server, just the drupal instance.

Comment: @roadzy if you have a static IP address it is somewhat likely that you can ask them to whitelist you.